# Geary doesn't validate account

Tags: email, mail, geary

Hello Ubuntu community,
   I have issue with email client Geary. When i try to validate account it doesn't validate it. I'm using Latvian mail service - inbox.lv. I have no trouble to use my mail accounts in Thunderbird in Elementary Luna, but Geary won't validate it. I even used same IMAP/SMTP setting wich i use in Thunderbird. After trying to validate account after 3 minutes of connecting i get this: "Unable to validate: IMAP connection error; SMTP connection error".

Mail provides me with this info:
 Incoming mail(POP3/POP3s)

```
 - E-mail address: login@inbox.lv
 - POP3 server: mail.inbox.lv
       POP3 server’s port: 110 (by default)
       POP3s server’s port: 995 (more info about POP3s)

 - SMTP server: mail.inbox.lv
       SMTP server’s port: 25(by default) or STMP server`s port: 587*
       SMTP server’s port with TLS support: 25 or 587* (more info about TLS)

* Some Internet Service Providers block port 25. It is possible for Inbox.lv users to send messages through mail.inbox.lv using port 587.  
 - Username: login
```

***Soo, guys, any idea to fix this issue? Thank you.***

Comment: What's the configuration for Geary?

Comment: By "configuration for Geary" you mean what? In the Preferences is four windows to select/deselect. Thats all what can i see - Reading, Composer, Notifications.

Comment: before going further i want to ask few things:- do u have enabled 2-step auth on Gmail. if yes ,u enable then you need to create app specific password through your google acc and paste code instead of password [this might help you](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1173270?hl=en)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geary does not support POP3, you will need an email server that supports IMAP.

(There's [a ticket for adding POP3 support](http://redmine.yorba.org/issues/5666) to Geary if anyone's interested in contributing a patch!)

Comment: I do not see how this answer explains "SMTP connection error". I've got it with IMAP.